# Get connection name and connection IP

Tags: c#, connection, dns, ip

it is possible get connection name and ip connection ip address in .net 2.0.

For example I have  2 connection on same pc.

Conn1  and  his IP is IP1
Conn2 and his  IP is IP2

I use this method:

```
    public Dictionary<string,string> GetLocalIP()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> _IP = new Dictionary<string,string>();

        System.Net.IPHostEntry _IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());

        foreach (System.Net.IPAddress _IPAddress in _IPHostEntry.AddressList)
        {
            _IP.Add(_IPAddress.AddressFamily.ToString(),_IPAddress.ToString());
        }
        return _IP;
    }
```

But I don’t know how can I retrieve connection name. I need have a pair connection name + connection IP.

Comment: why don't you step through the code a\nd view the variables top see there properties. would be much faster ;)

Comment: @RobertPitt: What about you talking?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the "adapter name" for each IP address, then I believe that the .net libraries don't provide this - so instead you will need to look at platform specific PInvoke code.

For an example of this, there are a few demo projects and open source examples out there - e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Net_Adapter_Info_in_C_.aspx